# Immigration Proposal

Tags: discussion

For some time there's been  the problem of immigration questions on here, and there's been tentative hope of an immmigration.SE - and indeed, there's an [Immigration/Expat](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) proposal.

Now, [said immigration/expat proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) has actually reached enough followers, but needs more questions / votes for those questions to reach the next level. I encourage anyone with some time to have a look and see if they can help out.  It'll give those off-topic posts a real home - somewhere to have their questions answered.

Comment: If they're short on questions, then some kind people could possibly pull together a list of the good-looking but off-topic ones we've had here, and add it to the proposal!

Comment: @Gagravarr +1 That should be no problem. There are enough pepople aroumd here ranting about these questions ;-)

Comment: @Gagravarr they actually have enough questions (they have 67), but need 15 questions with > score of 10 or more.  Currently they have 2, need 13 more. Votes help.

Comment: Isn't it 40 questions >10 that a proposal needed? They already have several pages of >10 ones, but 13 more are needed!

Comment: Yeah sorry, two mistakes.  '7' left off of '27' (so I said 2) and have no idea where the 15 came from.

Comment: J think an earlier version of Area51 needed 15 on-topic and 15 off-topic questions, but that hasn't been the case for a while now

Comment: They're down to needing 11 more.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The site is now in [Public Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) with stats that would indicate just a couple more Qs per day and it would take wing. TSE can spare a couple a day and has many Qs that, to my mind, are a better fit for Expats. We should be less reticent about migration.